# How to stop Ubuntu loading/booting up?

Tags: startup

I have loaded Ubuntu 11.10 onto my Windows 7 netbook.

Now, I think it loaded onto drive D. When starting the netbook it will automatically go into Ubuntu start up and I have no options to start Windows!

Please help, how do I get my Windows 7 back? :-/

Nigel

Comment: Press `shift` as soon as your bios splash ends, that should give you grub menu to choose installed OS if grub is your bootloader.

Answer (score 2):

You have to press the Shift during the boot sequence to get the grub loader menu.
Then you can select the operating system to boot.

Answer (score 0):

As similar your question, I have two operating system on my system- ubuntu 11.10 and XP.
when I boot the system then it gives me 5 option for booting like (but not exact)

1. boot from ubuntu
2. boot from ubuntu (recovery mode)
3. boot for memory check
4. boot for memory check(recovery mode)
5. boot for XP professional

here i can choose my boot option for booting XP.

I think you also have this windows on your system boot time to select your OS

Answer (score 0):

Install startup manger by typing this in terminal
`sudo apt-get install startupmanager`

Open `startup manager` located in system-->administration
In boot options tab:-
Timeout put it to some time (5 to 8 secs preferably)
Default operating system - put it to windows if you want Windows to boot up first.
hope this helps.