# No Grub menu after installing 11.10 64b on top of Windows 7 home Pro 64b

Tags: 11.10, grub2, 64-bit, windows-7, menu

I've installed -correctly- Ubuntu 11.10 64b on top of Windows 7 Home Pro 64b but the Grub menu is not showing on laptop boot.
The laptop is a Samsung rv420. I ran a tool called boot-repair but didn't apply suggested patches. I generated a log instead, which follows:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/930272/

So, which should be the instructions I should execute in the Ubuntu LiveCD so I can make grub show correctly? Of course, without crapping Windows installation

Thanks

Comment: You have to press shift during boot.
Have a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/122508/how-to-stop-ubuntu-loading-booting-up.

Comment: Tried shift before windows screen several times, without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try The terminal way? [RecoveringGrubMenu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

- Boot Ubuntu Live-CD
- Open Terminal
- Type: `sudo grub-install /dev/XXX` where XXX is the device of your Ubuntu install, in your case sda
- Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it
  does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose
  between Ubuntu and Windows.